# Removing references with the help of Python in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I have been trying to write a script for removing multiple references from a Maya scene. I've tried a lot for things but it would be really helpful if someone could show me the solution for this.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

ref=('*Proxy_RN')
cmds.referenceQuery(ref, referenceNode=True, parent=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.